# postgres returns only one record , many records needed

Tags: postgresql, express, node-pg-pool

so i'm going through this app i did the api request succesfully but in my table i have more than one record and the query returns me only the first column

```
router.get('/OnePost', (req,res)=>{
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'configSecret', (err, authData) => {
    if(err) {
              res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {     
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE userid = $1";
        const value = [authData.ID] ; 
            connection.query(sql,value)
            .then(response => res.json(response.rows[0]))
            .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Well, you're only sending the first row, not all rows? Drop the array element access from `response.rows[0]`

Comment: "*returns me only the first column*" - column or row?

Comment: i fixed it , thank you !!